# Are all Weil divisors principal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I've been studying Weil divisors from Vakil's FOAG Chapter 14.2. I'm somewhat confused, as to why *every* Weil divisor on a Noetherian normal irreducible scheme $X$ needn't be principal. My reasoning is as follows.

Let $D = \sum_Y n_Y[Y]$ be a Weil divisor. Now, for each codimension 1 point in $\operatorname{Supp} D$, we have a uniformizer $f_Y$. Now, considering the element $f = \prod f_Y^{n_Y}$ of $K(X)^{\times}$, don't we have that $\operatorname{div} f = D$?

I would glad if someone could explain where I am going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: A formatting tip for the future: `$\operatorname{Supp}$` produces $\operatorname{Supp}$, which handles spacing better. I've made the upgrade on your post this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uniformizer $f_Y$ may have zeroes or poles somewhere else, and this scuppers your argument. For instance, if $X=\Bbb P^1_k$, then taking standard coordinates, a uniformizer for the point $[0:1]$ is $\frac{x_0}{x_1}\in k(\Bbb P^1)$ which has a pole at $[1:0]$ and therefore $\operatorname{div} \frac{x_0}{x_1}=[0:1]-[1:0]$.